# Pandas warning when using map: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I've got the following code and it works. This basically renames values in columns so that they can be later merged.

```
pop = pd.read_csv('population.csv')
pop_recent = pop[pop['Year'] == 2014]

mapping = {
        'Korea, Rep.': 'South Korea',
        'Taiwan, China': 'Taiwan'
}
f= lambda x: mapping.get(x, x)
pop_recent['Country Name'] = pop_recent['Country Name'].map(f)
```

> Warning:
>   *A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>   See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>     pop_recent['Country Name'] = pop_recent['Country Name'].map(f)*

I did google this! But no examples seem to be using map, so I'm at a loss...

Comment: How did you get pop_recent ?

Comment: Try what the warning is telling to - pop.loc[(pop['year'] == 2014), 'Country Name'] = pop.loc[(pop['year'] == 2014), 'Country Name'].map(f)

Comment: Isn't this unnecessarily complex? I've already filtered out values other than 2014.

Comment: That filtering is the issue. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is with [chained indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) , what you are actually trying to do is to set values to - `pop[pop['Year'] == 2014]['Country Name']` - this would not work most of the times (as explained very well in the linked documentation) as this is two different calls and one of the calls may return a copy of the dataframe (I believe the boolean indexing) is returning the copy of the dataframe).

Hence, when you try to set values to that copy, it does not reflect in the original dataframe. Example -

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9

In [7]: df[df['A']==1]['B'] = 10
/path/to/ipython-script.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  if __name__ == '__main__':

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9
```

---

As noted , instead of chained indexing you should use `DataFrame.loc` to index the rows as well as the columns to update in a single call, avoiding this error. Example -

```
pop.loc[(pop['year'] == 2014), 'Country Name'] = pop.loc[(pop['year'] == 2014), 'Country Name'].map(f)
```

Or if this seem too long to you, you can create a mask (boolean dataframe) beforehand and assign to a variable, and use that in the above statement. Example -

```
mask = pop['year'] == 2014
pop.loc[mask,'Country Name'] = pop.loc[mask,'Country Name'].map(f)
```

Demo -

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9

In [10]: mapping = { 1:2 , 3:4}

In [11]: f= lambda x: mapping.get(x, x)

In [12]: df.loc[(df['B']==2),'A'] = df.loc[(df['B']==2),'A'].map(f)

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
   A  B
0  2  2
1  3  4
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9
```

Demo with the *mask* method -

```
In [18]: df
Out[18]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9

In [19]: mask = df['B']==2

In [20]: df.loc[mask,'A'] = df.loc[mask,'A'].map(f)

In [21]: df
Out[21]:
   A  B
0  2  2
1  3  4
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9
```

Comment: Aha... So if I first map, then slice (so the other way round), it works without bitching!

Comment: I hate Pandas. The impression I have is that it's one hack upon another with no consistency. As a more experienced user, what do you think?

Comment: If I do `pop = pop[pop['Year'] == 2014]`, the warning still exists. In this situation, isn't the original df will be released so we are tell pandas we want to set on the copy?

Comment: Also, I think one should slice the df again, as the OP is doing a map on the filtered piece. I find that's a lot of code for a single slice and map...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you **to reset indices** in `pop_recent = pop[pop['Year'] == 2014]`.

If you want to apply some function to some column of dataframe, try to use function [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function of DataFrame API. Simple demo:

```
 mapping = {
        'Korea, Rep.': 'South Korea',
        'Taiwan, China': 'Taiwan'
 }
 df = pandas.DataFrame({'Country':['Korea, Rep.', 'Taiwan, China', 'Japan', 'USA'], 'date':[2014, 2014, 2015, 2014]})
 df_recent = df[df['date'] == 2014].reset_index()
 df_recent['Country'] = df_recent['Country'].apply(lambda x: mapping.get(x, x))
```

Output:

```
>>> df_recent
index      Country  date
0      0  South Korea  2014
1      1       Taiwan  2014
2      3          USA  2014
```

Comment: No, sorry. It's still complaining: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead